# java fileinputstream available method returning always zero

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I have following piece of code :

```
fis = new FileInputStream(new File(st[0]));
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
while(fis.available()!=-1)
{
  System.out.println(br.readLine());
  System.out.println(fis.available());
}
```

The first println statement prints whole of my file but alongside second println statement always shows 0. why when there is actual content to read, is it showing 0 ?
and what should i put as end condition over here.

Comment: Why are you checking for -1? Where exactly does it say that available() will ever return -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to stop when readLine() returns null, something like this:

```
            String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> The first println statement prints whole of my file but alongside second println statement always shows 0.

You're checking `available()` twice. After you've read some data, it's no longer available to read, so the `available()` value printed is different to the one used for the loop condition above.

Secondly, you're reading from the BufferedReader, which does its own buffering of the data from the input stream. That means it's wrong to then sneak around the reader's back to call the available method of the underlying input stream!

Try this:

```
for (;;) {
    String line = br.readLine();
    if (line == null) break;
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

availabe() is returning the amount of bytes that can be read for that InputStream when it is not blocking. your readLine() is blocking that InputStream.

Comment: Not correct. It returns the 'number of bytes that can be read without blocking'. See the Javadoc. That's not the same thing as 'when it is not blocking'. *All* input streams are blocking, always.

Comment: Boann's answer is correct, and correctly stated too, but how that impinges on the incorrectness of your answer is a mystery to me.

Comment: OK, I'm spending my free time trying to help people here, If you keep stalking my comments and go on not being impartial I'll report it. Sorry mate